# Django Haystack - Delete an object from elastic index

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I had configured django-haystack with Elasticsearch as backend. And there is multiple connections in HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS all has elasticsearch as backend. So I need to add a custom delete signal in which the object instance will be removed from elasticsearch backend while deleting it from django model backend. I had coded this in haystack way, but nothing happens.

```
from haystack import connections

def delete_object_from_elastic_index(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.pop('instance')
    using = 'myIndex3'
    index = connections[using].get_unified_index().get_index(sender)
    index.remove_object(instance, using=using)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you link the delete signal with this method? If linked it will work only when we delete item individually, bulk delete won't trigger delete signal.

Comment: @Ranju R Yes, for me this code is executing for both bulk and individual(one time each in case of bulk) delete. But no effect can be found in elastic backend.